# How to trim database data having multiple spaces?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am getting data from database and I need to check the matching data entered by the user.
Unfortunately, I'm not getting it properly because of so many spaces in database records.

```
_usersinapplicationroles.All().Where(a => a.ApplicationRoleId == iAppRoleId && (Regex.Replace(a.User.DisplayName, @"\s\s+", " ").Trim() == Regex.Replace(strDisplayName, @"\s\s+", " ").Trim())).AsQueryable();
```

The above expression is wrong: not found 'a' due to regex before a.user.DisplayName.

Please correct this error.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this...

```
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", options);
```

replace below

```
Regex.Replace(strDisplayName, @"\s\s+", " ").
```

with

```
strDisplayName.Replace(strDisplayName, @" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove a white space from a string, use the following line:

```
string yourStringNoSpaces = yourString.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
```

In this way, you'll use:

```
_usersinapplicationroles.All().Where(a => a.ApplicationRoleId == iAppRoleId && a.User.DisplayName.Replace(" ", String.Empty) == strDisplayName.Replace(" ", String.Empty)).AsQueryable();
```

The above line was tested using a simple query in LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Thing> things = new List<Thing>();
    things.Add(new Thing(){
        Name = "test"
    });

    string testString = "te st";

    var result = things.Where (x => x.Name == testString.Replace(" ", String.Empty)).FirstOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine(result.Name);
}

class Thing
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: @user3106578 Which error do you have? I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Name itself having so many spaces in database.I need to avoid spaces of database data in code.